# Adding to the end of a list

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code for a project at school, however I have run into a problem.

Every time I run the code below, which is part of a sub-program to find the highest value in a text file.

```
intensity = input("Please select which Intensity level you would like to compare: Moderate or High?")     # Gets the intensity wanted
myFile = open("clientRecords.txt","r")     # Opens the file clientRecords.txt
lines = myFile.readlines()                 # Reads the lines in the file clientRecords.txt
myFile.close()                             # Closes the file to provide more space
print("LOADING...")
time.sleep(2)                              # Provides a suspence of 2 seconds
print()                                    # Prints a blank line
line_num = 0
list_a = []
while line_num != len(lines):
    current_line = lines[line_num].split(",")
    total = int(current_line[3]) + int(current_line[5]) + int(ent_line[7]) + int(current_line[9]) + int(current_line[11])
    list_a.extend()[total]
    line_num = line_num + 1
sortedList = bubblesort(list_a)
print(sortedList)
```

I have trouble adding the total variable to the end of the list in which it will be sorted.

Comment: Are you looking for `list_a.append(total)`?

Comment: Additionally I would like to point out that bubblesort is a very inefficient way to sort a list. Other better alternatives such as just [`sort`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_sort.htm) exist.

Answer (score 1):

`list_a.extend()[total]` is not a valid invocation of the `extend()` method on lists. `extend` is used to add another list at the end of the `list_a`. This would work if you wrote it as `list_a.extend([total])`, but that is just overkill, since you're creating an additional list for no practical reasons.

Instead, adding a *single* element at the end of a list is performed with `append()`, so in your case it should be `list_a.append(total)`.

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_a.append(2)

print(list_a)  # [1, 2, 3, 2]
```